# Powershell - Invoke-SqlCmd, retrieving PRINT statements asynchronously

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, powershell, printing, sqlcmd

I would like to know if its possibly to retrieve PRINT statements from a stored procedure asynchronously?

Currently the code below, only displays all the PRINT systems once the stored procedure has been executed.

```
"Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sql_server -Username $sql_usr -Password $sql_pwd -Database $sql_db -QueryTimeout 6000 -Query "EXEC TV.StoredProdure $cob_date, $region" -Verbose"
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean like this: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/post/Capturing-InfoMessage-Output-(PRINT-RAISERROR)-from-SQL-Server-using-PowerShell.aspx

Comment: @ShawnMelton - That still won't show it in real time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

`PRINT` will only display once the command has completed, whether you run it from OSQL, SSMS, or Powershell.

What you **CAN** do is use `RAISERROR` to get immediate feedback:

`RAISERROR('This will display immediately',0,1) WITH NOWAIT`